# Using gsub to replace a double quote with two double quotes?

Tags: awk

I'm trying write a script in awk that (among other things) replaces all instances of double quotes with two consecutive double quotes. But for some reason, I can't seem to escape my double quotes properly.

So for instance:

```
Mary had a "little" lamb
```

would become

```
Mary had a ""little"" lamb
```

Thanks kindly!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
echo 'Mary had a "little" lamb' | awk '{ gsub(/"/, "&&") } 1'
```

Output:

```
Mary had a ""little"" lamb
```

The `1` at the end invokes awk's default block `{ print $0 }`.

It's even shorter with sed:

```
echo 'Mary had a "little" lamb' | sed 's/"/&&/g'
```

Comment: Ah, that's interesting. As a more general AWK question, does AWK buffer the entire file into memory, and then act, or does it only operate on a per line basis? I guess what I'm trying to say is, is expensive memory-wise? (I can't approve your answer yet - I have to wait 5 minutes.)

Comment: @user1116858: awk only holds a record at time in memory, by default a record is a line.