# How to replace double quotes by escaped double quote in awk?

Tags: regex, awk

In awk how can I replace all double quotes by escaped double quotes?

```
The dog is "very" beautiful
```

would become

```
The dog is \"very\" beautiful
```

I've seen this answer ([Using gsub to replace a double quote with two double quotes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13870029/using-gsub-to-replace-a-double-quote-with-two-double-quotes)) and I've tried to adapt it, but I'm not very good with awk (and sed is no option because I work both on Linux and OS X and they have different 'sed' installed)

Comment: try `echo 'The dog is "very" beautiful' | gawk '{ gsub(/"/,"\\\"") } 1'`

Comment: @JoseRicardoBustosM. you should create your answer with that

Comment: @Fede i want to check using awk non gnu .... because OP have OS X

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you may to use with GNU awk:

```
echo 'The dog is "very" beautiful' | gawk '{ gsub(/"/,"\\\"") } 1'
```

you get

```
The dog is \"very\" beautiful
```

**explanation:**

for special characters `\` and `"`, you must to use escape sequence `\\` and `\"`

Comment: If someone else is using OS X, instead of 'gawk', just use 'awk'. Not sure if in linux you can just call 'awk' too

Comment: @pedrorijo91 In OS X you can install unix tools like gawk (it has also been ported), the easiest way is with package managers like Macports or Fink. Anyway gawk is an implementation of awk.

Comment: This code will work with all awks except possibly old, broken awk (/bin/awk on Solaris) which should never be used anyway.

Answer (score 14):

From the answer you linked:

With **gsub**:

```
echo 'The dog is "very" beautiful' | gawk '{ gsub(/"/,"\\\"") } 1'
```

Alternative, with **sed**:

```
echo 'The dog is "very" beautiful' | sed 's/"/\\"/g'
```

In both cases output is:

> The dog is \"very\" beautiful